# How to use DropDownPicker in class component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class, expo, react-native-dropdown-picker

This is what I have written so far---

[SnackLink](https://snack.expo.dev/@denton/picker)

The version of react-native-dropdown-picker is -- 5.4

I am new to react-native

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/9078341)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.